# C - Cannot get stack to initiate in my program

Tags: c, arrays, struct, stack, typedef

I am trying to create a stack but I am having a problem initiating it. The code that I have is:

```
#define LINELN 72    
#define STACKSZ 25    
#define NEWLN '\n'    
#include <stdlib.h>    
#include <stdio.h>  

// interface struct for stack
typedef struct stack {    
  char data[STACKSZ];    
  int top;    
} stack;    

void initstk(stack *s1);    
int emptystk(stack s);    

int main() {
  stack s1;
  initstk(s1);
  printf("%d",emptystk(s1)); 
  exit(0);
}

void initstk(stack *s1) {
  s1->top=-1;
}

int emptystk(stack s) {
  if(s.top == -1){
    return 1;
  }
  else{
    return 0;
  }
}
```

I want it to print out 1 since the stack is empty but it is print out 0 still. I don't really understand. Could it be because of the pointer?

Comment: I upvote your question as you posted a good [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3):

You declare:

```
void initstk(stack *s1);
/*...*/
int main() {
stack s1;
```

but then you invoke as:

```
initstk(s1);
```

Because `initstk` takes a pointer argument, you should pass the address of s1:

```
initstk(&s1);
```

I'm surprised your compiler didn't warn you about the mismatch.